# Flutter Error: Execution failed for task ':device_information:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, compiler-errors

Can not find any solution:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':device_information:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':device_information:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/shoebadnan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar.
> > /Users/shoebadnan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

You can go to `Android Studio -> Preferences -> System Settings -> Android SDK`

There uninstall and reinstall any partially installed things in the tabs SDK Platforms and SDK Tools. (or any things that have an update available).
You can do that by unticking the checkbox on the left, clicking Apply, then ticking the checkbox again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the the SDK version if it is over 23/29.
2. Set the

> buildToolsVersion As 21.1.1